# adding nonce to script tag for 3rd party code that breaks 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: javascript, nginx, webpack, content-security-policy

We are using netlify-cms that unfortunately emits code that break CONTENT-SECURITY-POLICY `'unsafe-eval'`.

I have tried adding `nonce` attributes to all the script tags using nginx `sub_filter`:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  set_secure_random_alphanum $cspNonce 32;
  sub_filter_once off;
  sub_filter_types *;
  sub_filter *CSP_NONCE* $cspNonce;
  sub_filter '<script' '<script nonce=\'$cspNonce\' ';
  sub_filter '<link' '<link nonce="$cspNonce" ';
```

I then add the nonce to the header also

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-$cspNonce' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' petstore.swagger.io;connect-src 'self' petstore.swagger.io";
```

I can see that the nonces in the script tags and the header all match:

```html
<script nonce='72UTQMpuXxfwcevvTydWt8XvOSzKhhjM' >
```

header

```
Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-77Fdz6e1aBiGr5b8qcReeUgkO2NtJnSm'
```

But I still get the error message:

> EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-77Fdz6e1aBiGr5b8qcReeUgkO2NtJnSm'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `'nonce-value'` you can get rid of `'unsafe-inline'` only, but not of `'unsafe-eval'`.

`'unsafe-eval'` in Netlify is required to compile JSON to JS code, but you can get rid of `'unsafe-eval'` too. Just update `ajv-json-loader` to use AJV 7 and Standalone mode and configure webpack config to use the updated loader. See nitty-gritty [here](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/issues/2138#issuecomment-961974783).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Do you mean that `nonce-value` is only good for `unsafe-inline`?

Comment: Yes, `'nonce-value'` (and `'hash-value'`) are applied to inline scripts and external scripts/styles. So they can be used to get rid of `'unsafe-inline'` in `scrips-src` and `style-src`. Whereas `'unsafe-eval'` covers creation functions from strings using `eval()` / `new Function()` / `setTimeout('string', )` / `setInterval('string', )`. `'unsafe-eval'` acts as a global page flag so it cannot be applied selectively.